# Updated-leetcode Implement atoi function giving wrong result for specific output

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My code for atoi function which converts string to integer is failing for "3.14159"

The link to the problem is 
[Atoi function](https://leetcode.com/problems/string-to-integer-atoi/)

```
INT_MIN=-2**31
INT_MAX=((2**31)-1)
class Solution:
    def myAtoi(self, s: str) -> int:
        result=0
        start=0
        flag=False
        if len(s)==0:
            return 0
        else:
            s=s.strip().split()[0] 
            if s[0]=='+' or s[0]=='-':
                start+=1
            if s[0]=='-':
                flag=True
            n=len(s)
            for i in range(start,n):
                if (ord('9')>=ord(s[i])) and (ord(s[i])>=ord('0')):
                    result = result*10 +(int(ord(s[i])-ord("0")))
                else:
                    result=result
                    #break
                print(result)
        if flag==True:
            result=-result 
        if result <INT_MIN:
            return INT_MIN
        if result >INT_MAX:
            return INT_MAX 
        return result
```

It is giving 314159 as output
but the expected output should be 3.
The value after decimal should be discarded.

The debugger statement is giving me

```
- 3
- 3 # the code should stop here
- 31# problem
- 314 # problem
- 3141 # problem 
- 31415 # problem
- 314159 #  problem
```

I tried using break in the else but, it gives 
IndexError: list index out of range

Can someone suggest to me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you try starting a debugger and going with it through the execution line by line to see what happens differently than you'd expect?

Comment: Yes, I did.
It is reading correctly till 4193 but after that when it is encountering the white space it should break and come out of the loop.
But based on the debug value my code keeps on reading till the end.

Comment: Then you know in which line you expected it to stop reading, but it continued? You should write here which line is behaving differently to what you expect and what are the values of relevant variables at that point. With that info, I'm sure someone on SO will be able to explain the problem.

Comment: @Ricky could you provide a proper link to the problem or explain the problem in your post? The provided link requires a premium account in LeetCode to view the problem.

Comment: `if (ord('9')>=ord(str[i])) or (ord(str[i])>=ord('0')):` should have an `and`. All characters have a code *either* less than 9 *or* greater than zero, but only 10 integers are both.

Comment: I have the correct link.

Answer (score 0):

Besides other suggestions, you need to replace:

```
str=(str.lstrip()).rstrip()
```

with

```
str = str.strip().split()[0]  # don't parse beyond the first space character
```